# HTML Image sizes & cycling functions

Tags: javascript, html, image, function, dhtml

So basically, I need to do something so that the images are not distorted and displayed in their original size. I tried adding them to the code with their actual width x height however that just shows up all of the images instead of fixing their size.

Also, need to change the previous() function so that when it reaches the first image it then displayes the last image - so it cycles around.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
myImages=new Array();
myImages[0]="w3schools.gif";
myImages[1]="bulbon.gif";
myImages[2]="landscape.jpg";
myImages[3]="w3schools.gif";
myImages[4]="bulboff.gif";
myImages[5]="smiley.gif";
imagecounter=myImages.length-1;
i=0;

function first()
{
document.getElementById('imageviewer').src=myImages[0];
i=0;
}

function previous()
{
if (i>0)
    {
    i--;
    document.getElementById('imageviewer').src=myImages[i];
    }
}

function next()
{
if (i<imagecounter)
    {
    i++;
    document.getElementById('imageviewer').src=myImages[i];
    }
}

function last()
{
document.getElementById('imageviewer').src=myImages[imagecounter];
i=imagecounter;
}

</script>
</head>

<body>
<center>
<img id="imageviewer" src="w3schools.gif" alt="w3Scools" width="100" height="30" />
<img id="imageviewer" src="bulbon.gif" alt="bulbon" width="100" height="180" />
<img id="imageviewer" src="landscape.jpg" alt="landscape" width="160" height="120" />
<img id="imageviewer" src="w3schools.gif" alt="w3Scools" width="100" height="30" />
<img id="imageviewer" src="bulboff.gif" alt="bulboff" width="100" height="180" />
<img id="imageviewer" src="smiley.gif" alt="smiley" width="32" height="32" />
<form>
<input type="button" value="First" onclick="first()">
<input type="button" value="Previous" onclick="previous()">
<input type="button" value="Next" onclick="next()">
<input type="button" value="Last" onclick="last()">
</form>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Part 1 of your question:

Each image is displaying at the same time because you are displaying them all at once. You'd need to have one element and drop in the element data for the specific image.

Full code for Part 1

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
myImages=new Array();
myImages[0]= {src:"http://cdn.impressivewebs.com/2014-02/w3schools-logo.jpg", width:"100", height:"30"}
myImages[1]= {src:"http://www.w3schools.com/js/pic_bulbon.gif", width:"100", height:"180"}
myImages[2]= {src:"http://www.ephotozine.com/epz.gif", width:"160", height:"120"}
myImages[3]= {src:"http://cdn.impressivewebs.com/2014-02/w3schools-logo.jpg", width:"100", height:"30"}
myImages[4]= {src:"http://www.w3schools.com/js/pic_bulbon.gif", width:"100", height:"180"}
myImages[5]= {src:"http://www.ephotozine.com/epz.gif", width:"32", height:"32"}

i=0;

first();

function first()
{
    console.log('first');
    document.getElementById('imageviewer').src = myImages[0]["src"];
    document.getElementById('imageviewer').style.height = myImages[0]["height"];
    document.getElementById('imageviewer').style.width = myImages[0]["width"];

    i=0;
}

function previous()
{
    if (i>0) {
        i--;
    }
    else {
        i = myImages.length - 1
    }
    document.getElementById('imageviewer').src = myImages[i]["src"];
    document.getElementById('imageviewer').style.height = myImages[i]["height"];
    document.getElementById('imageviewer').style.width = myImages[i]["width"]; 
}

function next()
{
    if (i<myImages.length) {
        i++;
        document.getElementById('imageviewer').src = myImages[i]["src"];
        document.getElementById('imageviewer').style.height = myImages[i]["height"];
        document.getElementById('imageviewer').style.width = myImages[i]["width"]; 
    }
}

function last()
{
    document.getElementById('imageviewer').src = myImages[myImages.length - 1]["src"];
    document.getElementById('imageviewer').style.height = myImages[myImages.length - 1]["height"];
    document.getElementById('imageviewer').style.width = myImages[myImages.length - 1]["width"];              
    i=myImages.length - 1;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<center>
<img id="imageviewer" src="smiley.gif" alt="smiley" width="32" height="32" />
<form>
<input type="button" value="First" onclick="first()">
<input type="button" value="Previous" onclick="previous();">
<input type="button" value="Next" onclick="next();">
<input type="button" value="Last" onclick="last();">
</form>
</center>
```

For Part 2 of your question:

Add an else to your if statement that sets `i` to be equal to the length of your array minus 1.

```
function previous() {
    if (i>0) {
        i--;
    }
    else {
        i = myImages.length - 1; //-1 because arrays are 0-indexed
    }
    document.getElementById('imageviewer').src=myImages[i];
}
```

Working example -> https://jsfiddle.net/9qhneheL/

Comment: Also when I do what you said for part 2 and the previous function doesn't work now

Comment: Full code added. Since you are new I'm not going to be a dick, but you really don't seem to understand how Stackoverflow works. This site isn't really for "give me the answer" type things. Its more for pointers to solve a specific problem you are stuck with. I hope you stick around and embrace the SO community.

Comment: Also, if I wanted to do the same thing to function next() as to function previous() what way would I do it? Just changing the "i = myImages.length - 1" value?

Comment: You'd do `else { i = 0 }`